# Keras shared layers with different "trainable" flags

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to use the functional API to have a shared layer where only one of the paths is trainable:

```
a_in = Input(x_shape)
b_in = Input(x_shape)
a_out = my_model(a_in)  # I want these weights to be trainable
b_out = my_model(b_in)  # I want these weights to be non-trainable (no gradient update)
y_out = my_merge(a_out, b_out)

full_model = Model(inputs=[a_in, b_in], outputs=[y_out])
full_model.compile(...)
```

I can't figure out how to do this though.  Setting the `my_model` trainable flag affects both layers.  I can compile 2 different models with different trainable flags, but then I can't see how I could combine 2 pre-compiled models to optimize my single merged cost function.

Is this even possible to do with Keras?  And if not, is it possible in TensorFlow?

Comment: It doesn't matter if its possible with Keras or Tensorflow, I think it conceptually makes no sense to share a layer weights and make it trainable with one input, but no trainable with another. Its just inconsistent.

Comment: My example here is just a minimal case for Stack Overflow.  But in my real project, it's an experimental generator/discriminator setup and I can't have the generator path update the discriminator and vise-versa.  There is *absolutely* strong use cases for this technique.

Comment: Are you making a GAN? Because that would be a completely different example.

Comment: Its a GAN, but not a traditional one.  I'm trying to have a unified cost function with a single model instead of interleaving the training of 2 models.  This is an experiment I'd like to test, so I'm only interested in solutions to my original question, not alternative GANs, since I have a bunch of those working already.

Comment: Do you mean you only want `my_model` to be updated w.r.t. `a_out` although `my_model` is used to produce `b_out` as well? If so, you can make an alias like `b_out2 = Lambda( lambda t : K.stop_gradient(t))( b_out )` to explicitly stop the graident backpropagation.

Comment: I suppose that works if there are no gradient updates before it, but it wouldn't solve the problem in general.  Could a lambda be used to take a copy of the weights of a fixed layer and just apply them directly?  I can imagine the fixed weights themselves as another input to the network, but that seems too messy/hacky...

Comment: @KevinH, did you find a solution? I am also trying to implement a multi-output network with shared weights and different trainable flags. So far, calling in a loop `train_on_batch` on two models with shared weights seems to be the only option - which I haven't tried yet.

Comment: @winterlight did you find any solution? I'm also looking for a way to generate such a training setup.

Comment: @LorenzoD'Arsiè, I did not find. I have not looked for it recently.

Comment: @winterlight, thanks, I've found a workaround, but it's an approximation, not what I'd like to do.

Answer (score 0):

If using pure keras, use keras.backend.stop_gradient inside a lambda layer, and pass b_out through that layer.

If using TF2, you can just use tf.stop_gradient and tf.keras will create the lambda layer for you.